# Aptana Studio no longer loading after High Sierra Upgrade

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

Been using Aptana Studio for years now, never had any issues (outside of Java Versions), until now.  I upgraded my MBP to High Sierra and Aptana stopped working - I installed all the relevant Java versions prior to running it as well just in case.  As It happened I also got a new MBP from work, so after a clean install of High Sierra, and Java, I installed Aptana and it again fails to load.

There is no error code displayed, I just get the Generic MacOS error window about a bug report.

Has anyone else had this issue, and if so have you managed to solve it.

I have installed Eclipse Oxygen (the Javascript version) and that launches OK, strangely the php version doesn't though - so it may be an issue with teh Eclipse base that Aptana uses (?).  I am using that for the time being, but much prefer Aptana.

Cheers

Comment: Need help here too please.